# debug a app with nativescrip and Google Chrome, not find app.js

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, nativescript

I'm looking to debug a simple application that I'm developing, but it does not display the application app.js entry point file.

What are the major steps to get started in debugging with NativeScript after:

1. Enter the command: `tns debug android`
2. Enter URL: `chrome-devtools: //devtools/bundled/inspector.html? Experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000`

I followed the two steps but I do not find the `app.js` file to activate the breakpoint at the point you want to monitor, exactly in this file.

Here is the initial code of the file and follow the link screen above:

[image: Chrome Debug Window]

All NativeScript components versions information

`┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 3.1.3           │ 3.1.3          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 3.1.0          │ Not installed │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing `app.js` script is because the script has already executed, and been forgotten about by the time the chrome devtools debugger establishes a connection with the V8 runtime.

In order to debug a NativeScript from the beginning, you want to place `debugger;` statements in the desired places in your scripts that execute early, then running `tns debug android` with the `--debug-brk` flag will break the application on the first script parsed (most commonly `ts_helpers`). `Continue` program execution, and if your debugger statement is in the path of execution, it will eventually break where you expect it to.

The reason you need to place `debugger` statements is because scripts are not parsed on the main thread while execution is paused, and therefore they don't show in the Sources panel.

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/chrome-devtools#debugger